# Adjust symmetry on Retopoflow

Tags: mesh, add-on

I'm trying to do some retopology to a simple model with Retopoflow but the symmetry is being miscalculated. I don't see any option to adjust this and the center of the object is already at the center of the mesh and the origin of the scene. How could I repair this? Thanks in advance! 
[image: Current model with wrong symmetry]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I just found the solution. To adjust this just exit Retopoflow, pick the Retopoflow object and you will see it's using a mirror modifier. Align the origin of the mesh with the one of the object you're retopologizing and go back to Retopoflow, the mirror will be fine now.